# Compile SDL with cabal in MinGW

Tags: haskell, mingw, sdl, cabal, sdl-1.2

I’m trying to install SDL within cabal for Haskell, in MinGW, but I got some problems. cabal can’t find the C library, and I don’t know why. Here some info:

- I have downloaded both the dev and runtime library of the SDL1.2 ;
- For the dev version, I `make native` it: it’s installed in `/usr/include/SDL` and `/usr/lib` ;
- I tried a `cabal install SDL`, it failed because it can’t find both the header file and the lib ;
- Then, I give it another try with `cabal install SDL --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include/SDL --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib`. It finds the header file but still not the lib ;
- I copied the runtime library `SDL.dll` in `/usr/lib`, still have the same trouble ;
- Finally, I added `/usr/lib` to both the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, still can’t find that @!#* C lib.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: This may be "superstition" as I've never found out a reason for it, but supplying --extra-include-dirs and --extra-lib-dirs seems to want Windows style full paths when I build with MinGW / SYS and "runhaskell Setup ..." (I don't use cabal install). For SDL I edit the cabal file changing these fields "Include-Dirs:   C:\msys\1.0\include\SDL" and "Extra-Lib-Dirs: C:\msys\1.0\lib"

Comment: @stephentetley: The most likely reason for that sort of behavior is when GHC and/or cabal are Windows applications that expect Windows behavior, but you invoke them from a pseudo-unix environment that translates stuff for the benefit of applications that expect a unix-like environment, at which point boundless hilarity ensues as you try to figure out which style of path works where.

Comment: Last time I checked, this worked: http://www.animal-machine.com/blog/2010/04/a-haskell-adventure-in-windows/

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari I tried to follow the link you gave me, the problem remains the same: ghc can’t find the C lib. The weird thing is that I *see* the `libSDL.dll.a` and `libSDLmain.a`, I correctly set the `Extra-Libraries`, `Include-Dirs` and `Extra-Lib-Dirs` though…

Comment: How come you go through all these /usr/* dirs? Litterally dumbly following that tutorial worked for me. What exact error message do you get from cabal/ghc?

Comment: It fails to pass the step just after the edition of the SDL.cabal file. I run `runghc Setup.lhs configure`, and it says that there’s `Missing C lib: SDL.dll, SDLmain`.

Comment: I spent much time struggling this problem too. Only switching to SFML did the thing for me.